# How to reserve first segment of URI as path in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I've controller files in Codeigniter Like:

```
Folder1
  UserController
  LoginController
  SignupControler
Folder2
  AccessController
  BottomController
```

Now, I want to access that controller something like:

```
http://example.com/folder1/usercontroller
http://example.com/folder2/bottomcontroller
```

How can I route **URI** So that, above thing can be accomplished?

Comment: dont use codeigniter, but are you looking for wildcard routes or autoloader?

Comment: Autoloader would be okay, but wildcard may also work. By the way, why not to use CodeIgniter?

Comment: sorry i meant to say "I dont use codeigniter" left out the "I" :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|js|system)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

this will remove  .php